# Can't make list of bluetooth devices present around in ionic2

Tags: html, angularjs, bluetooth, ionic2

I want to show a list of the bluetooth devices present around in Ionic2.

I made .ts and .html page in Ionic.

Now I can turn on bluetooth on my phone using the app, but can't see other devices.

.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BluetoothSerial } from 'ionic-native';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html'
})
export class Page1 {
public working:string;
public var2: string ;
public lists = [];

  constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController, public platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      BluetoothSerial.isConnected()
      .then(() => {
          console.log('is connected');
      }, (err) => {
          console.log(' not connected')
      })
    });
  }

  enableBluetooth(){
    BluetoothSerial.enable()
  }

  discoverBluetooth(){   
    /*   BluetoothSerial.setDeviceDiscoveredListener(function(device) {
      console.log('Found: '+device.id);
    });*/
  }

  unpairedBluetooth(){
    BluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired().then(function(devices) {
      devices.forEach(function(device) {
        console.log(device.id)
      });
    })
  }

  listDevices(){
    BluetoothSerial.isEnabled().then((data)=> {
      console.log(data);
      BluetoothSerial.list().then((allDevices) => {
        this.lists = allDevices;
        let result = [];
        for (var out in this.lists) {          
          result.push(out);
        }
      })
    })
  }}
```

.html file:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Page One</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>


    <ion-buttons>
<button ion-button (click) = "enableBluetooth()">Turn on bluetooth</button>
</ion-buttons>
 <ion-buttons>
<button ion-button (click) = "listDevices()">List devices</button>
</ion-buttons>

    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let out of lists">{{out}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>

 <ion-buttons>
<button ion-button (click) = "unpairedBluetooth()">Unpair</button>
</ion-buttons>
</ion-content>
```

I have response in my application but it only shows:

```
[object Object]
```

How can I read these?

Answer (score 0):

i think in this line :

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let out of lists">{{out}}</ion-item>
```

change `{{out}}` to something like `{{out.name}}` , out is complex object but you should display key of object. if you want where name is come check this [Bluetooth Serial](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial#list)

```
[{
"class": 276,
"id": "10:BF:48:CB:00:00",
"address": "10:BF:48:CB:00:00",
"name": "Nexus 7"
}]
```